# Values on browser are different as compared to the ones stored in database php

Tags: php, mysql

i generated a random number to use as a tracker but the random number generated is not the same as the one stored in the database.

Php Code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="name-card" class="text-success"><strong><?php echo $NUMEROENVIO; ?></strong></label>
    <?php
        $qryEmpresa =  mysql_query("SELECT * FROM company");

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($qryEmpresa)) {
            $pre  = $row["prefijo"];
            $cons  = $row["cons_no"];
        }

        mysql_free_result($qryEmpresa);

        $pa=mysql_query("SELECT MAX(cons_no)as maximo FROM c_tracking");

        if($row=mysql_fetch_array($pa)){
            if($row['maximo']==NULL){
                $cons_no=''.$cons.'';
            }else{                                                       
                $cons_no='100'.RAND(0,999999.99);
            }
        }

    ?>
```

how do i store the same random number generated to my database and not have two different numbers? Thank you!

Comment: Can you give multiple sample of the number generated and number entered to the db

Comment: @ArchitGoyal so this random number (IAS-10062438) for instance is generated on the text field but when i look into my db it is stored as (IAS-100523345). Another is (IAS-10043365) but it stored in my db as (IAS-100444702) it goes on and on.

Comment: Not sure I follow your logic. You are retrieving `MAX(cons_no)` from the DB. If nothing is found, `if($row['maximo']==NULL)`, you use `$cons` which comes from the `company` table. If a row is found, you then generate a new random number, `$cons_no='100'.RAND(0,999999.99);`.

Should be:

Use PHP to generate a random number. Store it in a variable. Save that number to the DB. Use that same number to display it to the user.

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It's awful and has been removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) helps explain best practices. Make **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will end up with severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: This code never saves, it only generates.

Comment: @tadam how do i save it ?

Comment: @tadman i plan on changing that on  all queries  been used.

Comment: If you never save the value how can you expect this to produce matching results with a *random number generator*?